# How can I stabilize a video using FFMPEG in Android

Tags: ffmpeg-php

I have built and successfully imported FFMPEG library in the android studio. How can I develop a program to stabilize a video using that?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should implementate ffmpeg library with vid.stab like
   https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg
2. You should give read/write storage permission
3. You should execute two ffmpeg commands:

`-y -i $VIDEO -vf vidstabdetect=shakiness=10:accuracy=15:result=${VIDEO}trfFile -f null -`

`-y -i $VIDEO -vf vidstabtransform=smoothing=30:input=${VIDEO}output.mp4 -c:v mpeg4 /storage/emulated/0/Android/output.mp4`

Where VIDEO is constant of your video path

It takes a lot of time because FFMPEG can't use phone GPU and render takes 2 minutes of 6 seconds of video.