# Stabilizing video using FFMpeg in Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-stabilization

I am trying to stabilize a video using FFMpeg in Android. I am currently using the FFmpeg-Android-Java library but I have also tried MobileFFmpeg as suggested by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172780/how-can-i-stabilize-a-video-using-ffmpeg-in-android) and also FFmpegKit.

I can get the deshaking filter to work but it made my video more shaky so I'm trying to get vidstabdetect and vidstabtransform to work but all the libraries I've tried give me "No such filter: 'vidstabdetect'"

Any ideas how I go about getting vidstabdetect and vidstabtransform to work?

Comment: Correct. Do you know a library I can use that has libvidstab enabled?

Comment: Thanks. I was using com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-full:4.5 When I changed to com.arthenica:ffmpeg-kit-min-gpl:4.5 that solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [FFmpeg vidstabdetect filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vidstabdetect-1) your `ffmpeg` has to be compiled with `--enable-libvidstab` to use the vidstabdetect and vidstabtransform filters.

The min-gpl, https-gpl, and full-gpl packages of [FFmpegKit](https://github.com/tanersener/ffmpeg-kit) (and same for the older, related MobileFFmpeg) support what they refer to as "vid.stab".